# Get the connection between files and folders in GDrive

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I have one simple Js method that just prints out contents of my Google Drive. I have messed around with samples provided by Google and I can print certain folders and files as I wish.

But I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow see what file is from what folder. Currently I have just list files and folders, also id's and mime types but I can't see any property or way to make sure what file comes from what folder.

Is it even somehow possible?

My sample code:

```
    /**
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
     */
    function listFiles(auth) {
        const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
        drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            const files = res.data.files;
            if (files.length) {
                files.map((file) => {
                    console.log(file);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('No files found');
            }
        });
    }
```

And this returns:

```
    { 
        kind: 'drive#file',
        id: 'example-id',
        name: 'example-file-name',
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the information of the parent folder of the file when the file list is retrieved by `drive.files.list()`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to use `drive.files.list()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification point:

- When the parameter of `parents` is used for `drive.files.list()` as `fields`, the parent folder ID of the file can be retrieved. By this, the information of the parent folder for the file can be retrieved.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
drive.files.list(
  {
    fields: "files(id, kind, name, mimeType, parents)"  // Added
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      files.map(file => {
        console.log(file);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No files found");
    }
  }
);
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, the parent IDs are retrieved. If you want to retrieve the parent folder names, please use `drive.files.get()`. Or after the folder list including the folder ID and folder name was retrieved using `drive.files.list()`, please retrieve the parent folder names from the folder list.
- Of course, you can also use `fields: "*"` instead of `fields: "files(id, kind, name, mimeType, parents)"`. In this case, it means that all fields are retrieved.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, that works. I even didn't think about possibility of having parents. Many thanks, got it working as I wanted.

Comment: @Kertix Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By the way, I added a tag of "node.js".